# find how long swing timer has been running

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm making a stop watch and I know how to do everything, except find how long my timer object has been going. Is there a method like `timer.getElapsedTime()` or something of that nature?

Edit: There are numbers saying 00 00 00. Every second it needs to increment. My thought process is `seconds = timer.getElapsedTime(); 
secs.setText(seconds)`

Comment: Can you provide a wider context to the problem? I suspect this isn't what you want to do at all, as if you're using a timer you shouldn't need this. Can you some code you have at current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save System.currentTimeMillis() in some variable when you set your timer, and compare the value to the current return value when you need the elapsed time.

EDIT: Make the timer fire once every second. Note that we re-set the timer every time it fires to prevent lag and processing time from accumulating.

```
package timertest;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class TimerTest implements ActionListener {

    JLabel timeDisplay;
    long startTime;
    Timer timer;
    int seconds;

    public void createAndShowGUI()  {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Stopwatch");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        timeDisplay=new JLabel("0");
        frame.getContentPane().add(timeDisplay);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        seconds=1;
        timer=new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TimerTest().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        long now=System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsed=now-startTime;
        seconds++;
        timeDisplay.setText(elapsed+" Milliseconds since start");
        timer.setInitialDelay((int)(startTime+seconds*1000-now));
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have specified a little more.I need the numbers to increment every second.

Comment: @ChrisVachon What numbers?

Comment: The stop watch says 00:00:00 and the next second it should say 00:00:01, then 00:00:02 etc. I probably should have specified. But I know how to do that if I can get how long the timer has been running.

Comment: In that case, i'd get the current time at the start, and set a timer to exactly 1000 ms. Every time the timer expires, get the current time, update the display, and re-set the timer to (original time + seconds - current time) - that way, you'll probably set the timer to something like 950 ms to account for lag and processing time, but your total time will match nicely, and you don't have to poll the timer at all.

Comment: How would I do that exactly? Something like `int seconds = 0; timer(1000, ActionListener); secs.setText(toString(second++)); timer.restart(); ` in a loop?

Comment: Give me a second, i'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Done. Note how i set the timer to 1000 ms at the start, then reset it according to the time difference every time it fires. You can omit the `setRepeats(false)` in `createAndShowGUI` and the `setInitialDelay` and `start` in actionPerformed, but in that case the milliseconds will count up; the version i posted always shows 1 or 2 ms only.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your own timer class. (Or inherit from the current timer class and add this functionality)

```
public class Timer
{
    private long startTime = 0;

    public void start()
    {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public int getElapsedTime() 
    {
        return (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000 //returns in seconds
    }
}
```